# Xamarin forms open view model on notification tap

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I am using this code to show notification in notification bar.  When the notification is tapped, main activity is launched.  Is it possible to launch the view model instead of activity in Xamarin forms app with MvvmCross.

```
 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,typeof(MainActivity));
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |                                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);      
   PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, code,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notify = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context);

    notify.setContentIntent(pIntent);
    notify.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon);
    notify.setContentTitle(“Title”);
    manager.notify(reqCode, notify.build());
```

Answer (score 1):

My idea was to make use of [`PutExtra`](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/activity/pass_data_between_activity/) in combination with [MessagingCenter](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/).

First, you show the notification in the notification bar:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Forms.Context, typeof(MainActivity));
if (openPage)
{
    intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
    intent.PutExtra("OpenPage", "SomePage");
}

const int pendingIntentId = 0;
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(Forms.Context, pendingIntentId, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

var nMgr = (NotificationManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
Notification.Builder notBuilder = new Notification.Builder(Android.App.Application.Context)
    .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .SetContentTitle("SomeApp")
    .SetContentText(message)
    .SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound | NotificationDefaults.Vibrate)
    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_launcher)
    .SetAutoCancel(true);

var notification = notBuilder.Build();
nMgr.Notify(0, notification);
```

In *MainActivity.cs* you check for the extra content:

```
protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    // Send message to the PCL (XF) if a certain page should be opened.
    if (intent.HasExtra("OpenPage"))
    {
        string pageName = intent.GetStringExtra("OpenPage") ?? "None";

        if (pageName != "None")
        {
            var message = new OpenPageMessage { PageName = pageName };
            MessagingCenter.Send(message, Message.Msg_OpenPage);
        }
    }

    base.OnNewIntent(intent);
}
```

And your central navigation instance (e.g. `MainPage`), subscribes to this message:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Message.OpenPageMessage>(this, Message.Msg_OpenPage, (async) message =>
{
    // Loads a certain page if a message is received

    switch (message.PageName)
    {
        case "SomePage":
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new SomePage(), true);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
});
```

Additionally, here is my *Message.cs*:

```
public class Message
{
    public const string Msg_OpenPage = "OpenPage";

    public class OpenPageMessage {
        public string PageName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

With the help of this [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44964328/426227).

**Edit**

There are issues if you have multiple push notifications at a time, where notfications where overwritten. One could use a different [`requestCode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)) or use [`FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT).

Comment: Hi, I have used 'put extra' for navigate to specific page while user click on push notification but some condition's it's fail. I have two type of notification i.e 1. order 2. review. When order type notification I have add order to put extra and when receive review type notification I have add review to put extra but when I click on order type notification's it's intent show 'review' extras. it save the last notification type. How can fix that.

Comment: I think it is better that you create a new question for that, where you better describe (e.g. with your code), what you want and where your problem is. I only used one notification type, so I can't reproduce your issue currently.

Comment: @Deepak: Have you found your solution? I think the problem is the [`requestCode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)) together with [`FLAG_ONE_SHOT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_ONE_SHOT). You could use [`FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT) or use a unique id for `requestCode`.

Comment: Interestingly, all the [docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/local_notifications_in_android/#starting-an-activity) uses the approach shown in my code, which leads to your problem. [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP) and [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) didn't helped me here. Perhaps one could explain the relationship better than me.