# Load Xamarin Forms page from android notification

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to load a Xamarin Forms page from an Android Notification. I am really lost on the android side of this, and most of my code has been pieced together from tutorials and blog posts. However nothing really seems to cover exactly this scenario.

I have implemented a very simple interface with dependency service to create the notification with an intent...

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(QuoteNotification))]

namespace QuoteApp.Droid
{

    class QuoteNotification : IQuoteNotification
    {


        public void Notify(string title, string message)
        {

            //type needs to be derived from java, not xamarin.forms
            Intent LoadPostPage = new Intent(Forms.Context, typeof(DroidToForms));
            const int pendingIntentId = 0;
            PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.GetActivity(Forms.Context, pendingIntentId, LoadPostPage, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(Forms.Context)
                .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .SetAutoCancel(true)

                     .SetContentTitle(title)
                     .SetContentText(message)
                     .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon);

            // Build the notification:
            Notification notification = builder.Build();

            // Get the notification manager:
            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

            // Publish the notification:
            const int notificationId = 0;
            notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, notification);
        }
    }
}
```

this calls an activity -

```
namespace QuoteApp.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "QuoteApp", MainLauncher = true)]
    class DroidToForms : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            StartActivity(typeof(XFPostPage));
            //Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new QuoteApp.PostPage());

        }
    }
}
```

which in turn calls this forms page, all the code here has been in Xamarin.Android project

```
namespace QuoteApp.Droid
{



        /// <summary>
        /// This is a Xamarin.Forms screen. It MUST:
        /// * inherit from ANdroidActivity
        /// * call Forms.Init()
        /// * use LoadApplication()
        /// </summary>
        [Activity(Label = "XFPostPage", MainLauncher = true) ]
        public class XFPostPage : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
        {
            protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
            {
                base.OnCreate(bundle);

                Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

            //LoadApplication( new App() ); //how do i send to PostPage.xaml ??

            Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new QuoteApp.PostPage());
        }
        }
    }
```

this gives the following error in logcat

```
07-04 17:51:44.494  7668  7668 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
07-04 17:51:44.494  7668  7668 E AndroidRuntime:   at QuoteApp.Droid.XFPostPage.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00016] in <ab64801c0fb24acb8457c1d1202cc143>:0
07-04 17:51:44.494  7668  7668 E AndroidRuntime:   at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x0000f] in <d855bac285f44dda8a0d8510b679b1e2>:0
07-04 17:51:44.494  7668  7668 E AndroidRuntime:   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:2780fa42-5931-40d3-8d14-a642f1a3025c (intptr,intptr,intptr)
07-04 17:51:44.494  7668  7668 E AndroidRuntime:        at md543d03747be5a5b03a21a2a23b8ba191a.XFPostPage.n_onCreate(Native Method)
07-04 17:51:44.494  7668  7668 E AndroidRuntime:        at md543d03747be5a5b03a21a2a23b8ba191a.XFPostPage.onCreate(XFPostPage.java:29)
07-04 17:51:44.494  7668  7668 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
07-04 17:51:44.494  7668  7668 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
07-04 17:51:44.494  7668  7668 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
07-04 17:51:44.494  7668  7668 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
07-04 17:51:44.494  7668  7668 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
07-04 17:51:44.494  7668  7668 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
07-04 17:51:44.494  7668  7668 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-04 17:51:44.494  7668  7668 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
07-04 17:51:44.494  7668  7668 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
07-04 17:51:44.494  7668  7668 E AndroidRuntime:        ... 3 more
```

I have tried a bunch of different ideas all with different runtime errors, my understanding of the Xamarin.Android workings are very limited. eventually i will be using the notification with AlarmManager and further information will be sent to PostPage.Xaml. At the moment i'm just lost at exactly where this is going wrong though?!

Any Help would be hugely appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: try use Page Renderer https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/contentpage/

Comment: Im not sure how that would load a Xamarin forms page from android, that seems to go the other way to load an android specific page in forms? unless i have missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with your code `Intent LoadPostPage = new Intent(Forms.Context, typeof(DroidToForms));`.

For Android platform of XF project, it only has one `Activity`, which is `MainActivity`, or pages of XF are rendered based on this `MainActivity`.

So you may change you code like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
intent.PutExtras(valuesForActivity);

PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);
```

Then in your `OnCreate` method of `MainActivity`:

```
//navigate to the page of PCL
Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new PostPage());
```

At last, as @Pratik suggested, if you want to create a native page/ view for Android platform, use `PageRenderer` or [ViewRenderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view/) to do so.

Comment: Thanks for that, That seems to be the advice I have read elsewhere too and I have tried it. It seemed to push the PostPage on startup everytime tho, which is undesirable. I have almost got it working using the OnNewIntent in main activity.

Comment: @Chrisco， " It seemed to push the PostPage on startup everytime tho, which is undesirable. " The point is that for XF, or pages are based on `MainActivity`, you can navigate to other pages according to the extras get from notification, but it's not recommended to intent a new activity from `MainActivity`.

Comment: Thank you, I have taken that point, my latest code is based on 'MainActivity' now.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using `OnNewIntent` in `MainActivity`.

there is some excellent information here [Processing notifications in Xamarin Forms Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43936784/processing-notifications-in-xamarin-forms-android)

My Code ended up looking like this.

Call the dependency service to get the android implmentation

```
DependencyService.Get<IQuoteNotification>().Notify("words",SelectedQuote.FixedTitle  , SelectedQuote.Id);
```

Which builds notification with the Intent:

```
  class QuoteNotification : IQuoteNotification
    {


        public void Notify(string title, string message, int postIndex)
        {

            //type needs to be derived from java, not xamarin.forms
            Intent LoadPostPage = new Intent(Forms.Context, typeof(MainActivity));
            LoadPostPage.PutExtra("NotificationTrue", true);
            LoadPostPage.PutExtra("PostID", postIndex);
            const int pendingIntentId = 0;
            PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.GetActivity(Forms.Context, pendingIntentId, LoadPostPage, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);
            

            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(Forms.Context)
                    .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .SetAutoCancel(true)
                    .SetContentTitle(title)
                    .SetContentText(message)
                    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon);

            // Build the notification:
            Notification notification = builder.Build();

            // Get the notification manager:
            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

            // Publish the notification:
            const int notificationId = 0;
            notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, notification);
        }
    }
```

then Override `OnNewIntent` in `MainActivity`. If the intent is not Built by my `QuoteNotification` class then send -1 as PostID

```
        protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent.HasExtra("NotificationTrue")){
            LoadApplication(new App(intent.GetIntExtra("PostID", -1)));
            //Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new QuoteApp.PostPage());
        }
        base.OnNewIntent(intent);
    }
```

Then in `App.Xaml.cs` add some logic to navigate to the correct page

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App(int PostId = -1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (PostId >= 0)
        {
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new PostPage(PostId));
        }
        else
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried above code it work' great but I have issue while user receive multiple type of notifications.  put extra only store latest value for example first I have save type1 and for second notification I have saved type2. When I click on type1 notification but it's intent extra value show type2 in 'OnNewIntent' method. Please suggest any idea.