# Move Android app to back when started from background

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I've added functionality to my Xamarin Forms Android app, to have it restart on a device (re)boot. That works ok (app is restarted).

This is the code of my BroadcastReceiver:

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]
public class BootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        if (intent.Action == Intent.ActionBootCompleted)
        {
            Intent newTaskIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
            newTaskIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            newTaskIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.FromBackground);
            context.StartActivity(newTaskIntent);
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see I've added the FromBackground tag to indicate that the app isn't started by the user, but from a background process.

What I like to achieve is that, when the app isn't started by the user, it should be pushed back and instead display the home screen, using this code (in the OnCreate event of the MainActivity):

```
this.MoveTaskToBack(true);
```

How can I check if the app wasn't started by the user, but by the BroadcastReceiver code?

NB: Please note that this is a "normal" user app with a UI, so it's not really a service. As Google's developer docs state (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) it's not advisable to start it as a service, as it will run in the main thread. My app should use a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

Add some extra values into your intent. Some sort of flag that you can read from your activity. Then pass that flag even further into your Xamarin.Forms.App. You can then check for that flag and see if the app was started by the receiver or not.

There is some code here that is similar to what you want to accomplish https://stackoverflow.com/a/44964328/1341538