# Xamarin Forms MessagingCenter does not receive message

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, messagingcenter

I have downloaded MultiImagePicker from this link : https://github.com/danielkon96/MultiImagePickerand it's working fine without any problem . When I add all interfaces and classes and... in my project , the MessagingCenter does not receive message .

ButtonClick in UploadPage:

```
MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<App, List<string>>((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "ImagesSelectedAndroid");
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App, List<string>>((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "ImagesSelectedAndroid", (s, images) =>
{
   if (images.Count > 0)
   {
      ImgCarouselView.ItemsSource = images;
      InfoText.IsVisible = true;
   }
});
```

OnActivityResult in MainActivity :

```
MessagingCenter.Send<App, List<string>>((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "ImagesSelectedAndroid", images);
```

What's the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @pinedax for his answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61284345/1786401) I have solved my problem by this changes :

```
MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<Xamarin.Forms.Application, List<string>>(Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "ImagesSelectedAndroid");

MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Xamarin.Forms.Application, List<string>>(Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "ImagesSelectedAndroid", (s, images) =>
```

and

```
MessagingCenter.Send<Xamarin.Forms.Application, List<string>>(Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "ImagesSelectedAndroid", images);
```

Comment: You can mark this answer later which will help more people with same problem:).

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Yes . Thank you . I will